# What is the vector form of an ellipsis' major and minor axis, given lissajous-figur notation for the ellipsis?

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

A lissajous figure is described by

$$ t \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} A_x \sin(ω_1t + φ_1)\\A_y \sin(ω_2t + φ_2) \end{pmatrix}, t\in \left[0,\infty\right] $$

for $ω_1 = ω_2$ you get a simplified form of 
$$ t \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} A_x \sin(ωt + φ)\\A_y \sin(ωt) \end{pmatrix}, t\in \left[0,\infty\right] $$

and the resulting shapes are ellipses.

I am looking for the vector form of the (major and) minor axis of those ellipses, expressed through $$A_x, A_y, φ$$. I am interested in the general form, so also for tilted ellipses, where the ellipse's axis' are not parallel to the cartesian coordinat axis.

Update: 
With the matrix C as provided by @amd I was able to calcualte the eigenvalues and eigenvektors, and with those i could calculate the direction vector (and the angle) of the minor axis of the ellipse. I did not manage to do the same with the formula for $$tan(2\theta)$$ that he provided. The calculation that I ended up using was:

```
def calc_vector2(x_abs, y_abs, phase_shift):

square_tan = (np.square(x_abs) + np.square(y_abs)) * np.tan(phase_shift)
sqrt = np.sqrt( -(np.square(np.sin(phase_shift)) * (np.power(x_abs, 4) + 2 * np.cos(2 * phase_shift) * np.square(x_abs * y_abs) + np.power(y_abs,4))) / (np.square(np.sin(phase_shift)) - 1))
xysin = x_abs * y_abs * np.sin(phase_shift)
frac = 2 * np.square(xysin) * np.tan(phase_shift)

eigenvalue_1 = (square_tan + sqrt) / frac
eigenvalue_2 = (square_tan - sqrt) / frac

if eigenvalue_1 >= eigenvalue_2:
    x_dir = -(np.square(y_abs) * np.tan(phase_shift) - np.square(x_abs) * np.tan(phase_shift) + np.sqrt(
        -(np.square(np.sin(phase_shift)) * (
                np.power(x_abs, 4) + 2 * np.cos(2 * phase_shift) * np.square(x_abs * y_abs) + np.power(y_abs,
                                                                                                       4))) / (
            np.square(np.sin(phase_shift)) - 1))) / (2 * x_abs * y_abs * np.sin(phase_shift))
else:
    x_dir = (-np.square(y_abs) * np.tan(phase_shift) + np.square(x_abs) * np.tan(phase_shift) + np.sqrt(
        -(np.square(np.sin(phase_shift)) * (
                np.power(x_abs, 4) + 2 * np.cos(2 * phase_shift) * np.square(x_abs * y_abs) + np.power(y_abs,
                                                                                                       4))) / (
            np.square(np.sin(phase_shift)) - 1))) / (2 * x_abs * y_abs * np.sin(phase_shift))
y_dir = 1
angle_off_minor_axis = np.arctan(y_dir / x_dir)
print("Winkel gegen die X-Achse: " + str(angle_off_minor_axis / np.pi * 180))
return angle_off_minor_axis, [x_dir, y_dir]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a somewhat roundabout approach, but it involves far less trigonometric chicanery than others that I can think of, so for my part I’m less apt to make a silly error somewhere along the way.

One way to interpret a Lissajous figure is as the projection of a sinusoid drawn on the surface of a cylinder. So, we can view this ellipse as the projection of the parametric curve $$\mathbf r(t) = \left(A_x\sin(\omega t+\phi),A_x\cos(\omega t+\phi),A_y\sin\omega t\right)$$ onto the $x$-$z$ plane. W.l.o.g. we can reparametrize this as $\left(A_x\sin(t+\delta),A_x\cos(t+\delta),A_y\sin t\right)$, since $\omega\ne0$ just controls how quickly the curve is traced out and $\delta = \phi/\omega$ determines where on the cylinder the sinusoid starts.

The vectors $\mathbf r(0)$ and $\mathbf r(\pi/2)$ are obviously linearly independent, and $$\begin{vmatrix}\mathbf r(t)^T\\\mathbf r(0)^T\\\mathbf r(\pi/2)^T\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}A_x\sin(t+\delta)&A_x\cos(t+\delta)&A_y\sin t \\ A_x\sin\delta& A_x\cos\delta&0 \\ A_x\cos\delta&-A_x\sin\delta&A_y\end{vmatrix}=0,$$ so $\mathbf r(t)$ is in their span $P$ for all $t$: this space curve is planar. Thus we can obtain it as the intersection of $P$ with the cylinder $x^2+y^2=A_x^2$. The vectors $\mathbf r(0)$ and $\mathbf r(\pi/2)$ happen to be semiaxes of this ellipse, which simplifies the following computations, but that particular choice of basis isn’t essential.

Let $$M = \begin{bmatrix} \sin\delta & \cos\delta & 0 \\ \cos\delta & -\sin\delta & 0 \\ 0 & A_y/A_x & 0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$ This matrix represents a homogeneous coordinate system on $P$: the spatial homogeneous coordinates $\mathbf X$ of any point on the plane are a linear combination of the columns of $M$, i.e., $\mathbf X=M\mathbf x$. If you prefer, you can think of that last formula as a parameterization of $P$.

The cylinder is represented by the matrix $Q=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0,-A_x^2)$, and in $M$-coordinates, its intersection with $P$ has the matrix $$C = M^TQM = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-A_x^2\end{bmatrix}.$$ If you’re familiar with matrix representations of conics, this might look like the matrix of a circle to you, but remember that the basis vectors that we’re using for $P$ have unequal norms.

We now obtain a homography between $P$ and the $x$-$z$ plane by multiplying $M$ by the appropriate orthogonal projection matrix, which just amounts to deleting the second row of $M$: $$H = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}M = \begin{bmatrix}\sin\delta&\cos\delta&0\\0&A_y/A_x&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Finally we apply this homography to $C$ to obtain the matrix of the ellipse represented by the original parametric equations: $$H^{-T}CH^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\csc^2\delta & -{A_x\over A_y}\cot\delta\csc\delta & 0 \\ -{A_x\over A_y}\cot\delta\csc\delta & {A_x^2\over A_y^2}\csc^2\delta & 0 \\ 0&0&-A_x^2\end{bmatrix}$$ which we can normalize to $$C' = \begin{bmatrix}\frac1{(A_x\sin\delta)^2} & -\frac1{A_xA_y\tan\delta\sin\delta} & 0 \\ -\frac1{A_xA_y\tan\delta\sin\delta} & \frac1{(A_y\sin\delta)^2} & 0 \\ 0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ corresponding to the Cartesian equation $${x^2\over(A_x\sin\delta)^2}-{2xy\over A_xA_y\tan\delta\sin\delta}+{y^2\over(A_y\sin\delta)^2}=1.$$ This is undefined for $\delta=n\pi$, but in that case we’re looking at $\mathbf r(t)$ edge on and the resulting Lissajous figure is a line segment rather than an ellipse.

From here you can use standard formulas and techniques to analyze the ellipse: the eigenvalues of $C'$ are inverse squares of the semiaxis lengths; the ellipse is inclined at an angle $\theta$ from the horizontal, where $$\tan{2\theta} = {2A_xA_y\cos\delta\over A_x^2-A_y^2},$$ and so on.

---

Eliminating $t$ directly from the original parametric equations yields the curious equation $\arcsin{\frac x{A_x}}=\arcsin{\frac y{A_y}}+\delta$. I haven’t pursued it any farther, but it does appear to have an interesting interpretation in terms of counterrotating points.

---

*Update:* It struck me that eliminating $t$ from the parameterization isn’t all that tricky after all. We immediately get $\sin t=y/A_y$. Expand $x=A_x\sin(t+\delta)$ using the sum-of-angles formula, substitute for $\sin t$ and solve for $\cos t$, then use the usual $\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$ to get $$\left({x\over A_x\sin\delta}-{y\over A_y\tan\delta}\right)^2+\left({y\over A_y}\right)^2=1.$$ Expanding and collecting terms results in the same equation as previously. Much less work than the original approach, but perhaps not as geometrically satisfying.

Comment: Thank you very much for your details writeup. I am impressed by the aparent ease with which you did this. 
However, I am less interested in the LENGTH of the minor axis of the ellipse, but in its direction vector. It is not obvious to me how to find that. Can you please help me out here? Also I am not sure how to get from the notiation with $\delta$ to one with just $A_x$, $A_y$ and $φ$, as $\omega$ would get re-involved if i just replace $\delta$.

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei From the top, $\delta = \phi/\omega$. For the axis directions, they are $\theta$ from the end of the answer and $\theta+\pi/2$. You’ll need to test to see which of these is the minor axis, but that’s fairly easy: both $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ are eigenvectors of the upper-left $2\times2$ submatrix of $C'$, so they’ll just get scaled by it. The one that gets scaled the _most_ corresponds to the minor axis.

Comment: It occured to me that $\theta$ is the inclination of either the major or the minor axis of the ellipse. How can I know which one it is? The length (see my comment above) would of course help to tell them apart, but I would not know which length goes with what angle, either.

Comment: this was a classical comment race condition. :-) thanks

Comment: I was aware of $\delta = φ / \omega$, but then I have the dependency on $\omega$ which I mentioned, and that is what I was unsure of how to handle. The ellipse's shape is independent of $\omega$ (except like what you mentioned - where it starts and stops -- which is not really relevant to me). How can I get to a form without $\omega$?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei You can’t. The shape depends on the phase shift $\phi/\omega$.

Comment: Oh, one more way to distinguish the axes: apply a rotation through $-\theta$ to $C'$, which should give you a diagonal matrix. The first two elements on the diagonal are reciprocal squares of the semiaxis lengths, the the _larger_ of the two corresponds to the minor axis. Not sure which of these two methods is more computationally efficient.

Comment: The phase shift (at least in the electrical engineering sense) is $φ$ - which expresses the delay against a unshifted wave. In my initial notation the $y$ component is the reference, as it comes without a phase shift: $A_y \sin(ωt)$. And I agree that the shape depends on $\varphi$. Could i perhaps just assume a convenient $\omega$ of 2π radians per second?

Comment: There are three parameters that control the shape: $A_x$, $A_y$ and the **ratio** $\phi/\omega$. Express that ratio in whatever form is convenient.

Comment: Thank you for adding the second way to distinguish the axis. I will try both to get a feel for them. Could you perhaps add those two ways to your original answer above? To me they seem to be very relevant in answering my initial question, even if the heavy lifting in the mathematical sense is done at that point. Before having actually done the math, I wonder how I should be able to tell weather $\theta$ or $\theta +\pi/2$ corresponds to one or the other matrix component. Perhaps that will become clear when I get there? That is unclear to me for both ways, right now.

Comment: for me the second, easier, way does not give the same equation then the first. The extra term $left({y\over A_y}\right)^2$ remains. Also, when using the term for $\tan{2\theta}$ in my code it does not seem to give me angles which are alined to the the minor axis. 

How did you do this - did you use some symbolic math program like sage or mathematica or is it possible that there are minor slip ups in the math?

Comment: Works for me. I mocked all of this up in GeoGebra when I originally tested the solution. Double-check your algebra and your code. When the last equation is expanded, the coefficient of $y^2$ is $1/A_y^2+(\cot^2\delta)/A_y^2$ which simplifies to $1/(A_y\sin\delta)^2$. There’s no left-over term.

Comment: You’ll likely also need to special-case $\delta = \pi/2+n\pi$. $\tan\delta$ is undefined there, but the ellipse is simply $x^2/A_x^2+y^2/A_y^2=1$, which you can obtain by using $\cot\delta$ in the equations instead.

Comment: https://send.firefox.com/download/e90cb72a6cb72dac/#k2fRFXcLtTcCcbmjxgN5Vg  Here is a link to the python code i wrote that reflects my understanding of the math, plus a little test case, demonstrating that it is not quite there yet. If you have hints, I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

The squared distance from the origin is $ A_x^2 \sin^2 (\omega t  + \varphi) + A_y^2 \sin^2 (\omega t)$, which can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
&\frac 12 A_x^2(1-\cos (2(\omega t+\varphi)))+\frac 12A_y^2(1-\cos (2\omega t))=\\=&\frac12(A_x^2+A_y^2)-\frac 12(A_x^2\cos(2\varphi)+A_y^2)\cos(2\omega t)+\frac 12A_x^2\sin(2\varphi)\sin(2\omega t)=\\=&C_0+C_1\cos(2\omega t)+C_2\sin(2\omega t)
\end{align}
If $C_1=C_2=0$ then the curve is a circle. Otherwise there is an angle $\psi$ such that

$\cos \psi=\frac {C_1}{\sqrt {C_1^2+C_2^2}} \text{ and }\sin \psi=\frac {C_2}{\sqrt {C_1^2+C_2^2}{}{}}$ , which leads to a squared distance $C_0+\sqrt {C_1^2+C_2^2}\cos(2\omega t-\psi)$ with clear minima and maxima.

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you. 
Can you please elaborate on how you got from the notation with C0, C1 and C2 to the introduction of psi  and that final form? (can i use nice math markup even in comments?)

Comment: It is simply a matter of replacing $C_1$ by $\sqrt {C_1^2+C_2^2} \cos \psi$ and $C_2$ by $\sqrt {C_1^2+C_2^2} \sin \psi$ in $C_0+C_1\cos(2\omega t)+C_2\sin(2\omega t)$ and using the trigonometric formula $\cos (x-y)=\cos x\cos y+\sin x \sin y$. (and yes, you can.)

Comment: Yes, that clarifies that. Thank you for your explonation. 
This does not really help me yet. I see that the distance to the origin  is minimal when $2\omega t - \psi = \frac{\pi}{2}$. That gives me my vector for the minor axis of the parabel. However we know that the two axis are independent of $\omega t$ - the lissajours figure is described completly by $A_x$, $A_y$ and $\psi$. By introducing $\psi$ you arrive at a form that has clear minima and maxima and therefor would be one step towards my goal (which was the vector form of the minor axis), but depends on more then those three variables.

Comment: Or do i misunderstand something? Perhaps i am just to tired. :-)

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei Just solve that expression of yours for $t$ and substitute back into the original parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

Calling your expression $h(t)$, it's clear that the shape traced out by $h$ is symmetric about the origin, so the ellipse-center is $(0,0)$. The squared distance from $h(t)$ to the origin will be maximized/minimized at each $u$-value for which $h(u)$ lies along the major/minor axis. Let's look at that:
$$
k(u) = \|h(u)\|^2 = A_x^2 \sin^2 (\omega t  + \phi) + A_y^2 \sin^2 (\omega t),
$$
Computing the derivative and setting to zero gives:
\begin{align}
0 &= k'(u) \\
& = 2\omega A_x^2 \sin (\omega t  + \phi)\cos (\omega t  + \phi)+ 2\omega A_y^2 \sin (\omega t)\cos (\omega t),
\end{align}
and dividing through by $\omega$ (your whole formula makes no sense if $\omega = 0$) we get
\begin{align}
0 
&= A_x^2 \cdot 2\sin (\omega t  + \phi)\cos (\omega t  + \phi)+ A_y^2 \cdot 2\sin (\omega t)\cos (\omega t)\\
&= A_x^2 \cdot \sin (2(\omega t  + \phi))+ A_y^2 \cdot \sin (2\omega t)\\
\end{align}
so that 
\begin{align}
-A_x^2 \cdot \sin (2(\omega t  + \phi)) &=  A_y^2 \cdot \sin (2\omega t)\\
-\frac{A_y^2}{A_x^2} = \frac{\sin (2(\omega t  + \phi))}{\sin (2\omega t)}
\end{align}

Defining $r(t) = \frac{\sin (2(\omega t  + \phi))}{\sin (2\omega t)}$, it's easy to see that $r$ is undefined when $t$ is a multiple of $\pi$, but also that $r$ is surjective onto $\Bbb R$, hence that there's some $t_0$ for which $r(t_0)$ is any particular value, in particular, when it equals the value prescribed by the left-hand side.

Your point $h(t_0)$ will lie along either the major or the minor axis.

Sadly, I don't know an easy expression for $t_0$, so this may be as far as you can get.

Comment: Another way to obtain your equation is by using $h\cdot h'=0$ at only the vertices and covertices.